# How to extract alphanumeric phrase from a string - if it doesn't exist I wish to flag it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that can have the following possible values -

1. ITO26218361281- JANE
2. SBC28791827135 VATS
3. SOT21092832917 JOHN DOE
4. TIM INQ12109283291
5. JANE DOE 12/15

I only want to extract the 14 characters
alphanumeric phrase from the strings that can look like above. If the record is like (5), I still want that record to exist to be able to call it out as an error. I don't need the exact text to be the same, I just need it to be flagged for error.

Result expected -

1. ITO26218361281
2. SBC28791827135
3. SOT21092832917
4. INQ12109283291
5. JANE DOE 12/15 (or flagged as error)

Comment: *"14 digit alphanumeric"*, but in the sample data, there's only 11 digit numbers. *"I just need it to be flagged for error"* how do you want to do that? insert invalid data in a temporary table, or update some column in own table?

Comment: @RicardoPontual hi! im sorry - i meant i want to extract the whole 14 characters alphanumeric phrase "INQ12109283291"

Is it possible to add a flag column in the same table? I just don't want the data to be completely stripped off from the table and need to show that it exists and has been entered "incorrectly" as in, NO alphanumeric characters have been entered.

Comment: I understood, I posted an answer with a simple query that can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match the pattern you need, 3 letters and 11 numbers.

Using this in `WHERE` clause, you can match all "valid" values:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableName
 WHERE ColumnName like '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

I'm not a master of patterns nor regular expression, so used a "simple to understand" pattern here.

With this query, you extract the data to other table, or `UPDATE` a table column with the flag you want.

You can see [this query working here in sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd1b2/3)